# mysql функция возврат всех значений

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Подскажите как реализовать. Есть функция на сервере,

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;
 DECLARE rs VARCHAR(50);
 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE counter INT;
 SET i = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoice WHERE STATUS = 'personAgree');
 SET counter = 1;
 WHILE i <= counter DO
 SET counter = counter +1;
 SET rs = rs + ':' + (SELECT id INTO rs FROM invoice WHERE STATUS = 'personAgree');
END WHILE;
RETURN rs;
 END
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы по запросу этой функции она собрала значение всех строк, удовлетворяющим критериям в одну переменную `rs` и вернула  эту строку. Но не могу понять как это правильно сделать?

Comment: * не осилил смысла функции. особено с условием `i < counter`, которое вряд ли выполнимо

Comment: @teran по аналоги с обычными языками программирования, посчитать сколько результата и для каждого добавить нужное значение к строке...

Comment: *Хочу сделать так, чтобы по запросу этой функции она собрала значение всех строк, удовлетворяющим критериям в одну переменную rs и вернула эту строку.* Какой смысл изобретать свою собственную [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Comment: @Akina не знал про эту функцию, спасибо!